# qt c++ QPainter with QVector, QPoint

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have `QVector<QPoint> m_vertices;`.

I am currently trying to implement simple drawing programm. I can draw multiple circles, but i also want to remove them from ***"mainwindow"***.

This is what i have a this moment

How can i improve my "DELETE_VERTEX_SELECTED" part ?

```
void DrawingWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    if(m_state == ADD_VERTEX_SELECTED) {
        if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            //m_x = event->x();
            //m_y = event->y();
            //update();
            QPoint point = event->pos();
            m_vertices.append(point);
            update();
        }
    }
    if(m_state == DELETE_VERTEX_SELECTED) {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_vertices.size() ; i++) {
            if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
                m_vertices.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```